# How to overwrite laravel fortify controllers

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-fortify

I need to overwrite the login,register,logout and 2FA methods to add some logic,
How can i publish it from the vendor?, is there something like `php artisan vendor:publish .....`

Comment: "Customizing The Authentication Process" https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-the-authentication-process

Comment: i need to add specific logic for each rule in login and register also change the redirect. i can't find what i need in this link.

Comment: i need way to publish this namespace "Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers"

Comment: You're probably better off *extending* those controllers. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/proper-way-to-override-jetstreamfortify-auth-routes has a guide to doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that i can overwrite any of fortify pipeline in FortifyServiceProvider
by adding the flowing inside boot() function:

```
# overwrite example
$this->app->singleton(LoginResponseContract::class, LoginResponse::class);
$this->app->singleton(RegisterResponseContract::class, RegisterResponse::class);
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a good solution to use a new controller by rewriting the desired route
Because then you will have more control power

```
Route::post('/register', [MyNewController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware(['guest:'.config('fortify.guard')]);
```